# Overheating using a i7 Intel processor while using Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, power-management

I use a Intel i7 Dell-laptop. I installed Ubuntu 12.04(64bit) from scratch. I realized the CPU temperature increased immediately(it's not difficult to detect temperature with this computer only by hand) . When I played flash players in youtube or elsewhere I saw in the system manager that only one core increased working frequency despite all other. And that core was like 80-90% while the others stayed at 5%. Any suggestions? Should I install 32bit version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been reading about a lot of issues with CPU overheating in Ubuntu, particularly with Sandybridge processors, with the blame being placed on all sorts from flash to internet explorer(?!).  From my own research and experimenting with different distros, it seems the issue is with the linux kernel.  12.04 was supposed to solve these issues, but the 3.2 kernel in this distro still doesn't seem to play well with sandybrige; I'm using 12.04 with a quad core i7, and while my overheating issues are not as extreme as some I've read about, it does non-the-less overheat, and harnesses nowhere near the full power of my processor.  Kernel 3.4 was supposed to bring, amongst other things, improved sandybridge performance;  I've installed the Ubuntu specific 3.4 kernel, and there is some improvement, but put into the context of what my processor is capable of (and fully achieves in Win7) it's still just not good enough.  Such a shame, I love Linux, and Ubuntu, but if it can't harness new tech, what's the point?

Comment: is there a way to install 32 bit ubuntu over my old installation without loosing all my programs and settings? :\ I can not work without my laptop cooler. I'm  disappointed.

Comment: That's not something I've ever tried, and but if I had to give an answer, I'd say no. If you're still keen to persevere with Ubuntu, you'll probably have to do a clean install. Having said that, if you're going to start from scratch anyway, why not back everything up and give it a go and see what happens; Ubuntu live CD supports installing over the top of existing installs. I'd be interested to know how it goes if you do decide to give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Flash is very poorly optimized to work on Linux, it probably will work kinda funky in whatever installation you might have.

So I would recommend switching to HTML5 version of Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/html5

**AND**

Also installing the CPU Frequency widget: https://launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq